# Last chance to review the 'accepted answer' feature!

Tags: discussion, voting

Six weeks ago, we were first asked on Meta whether we [still wanted accepted answers to appear prominently at the top of pages](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/should-accepted-answers-appear-first-just-above-the-highest-scored-answer-or-s) on *English Language Learners*.

Amazingly, over 500 of our users have visited this page! Surely a great testament to the involvement of users on our site!

When the question was first posted, this seemed like a quite a simple choice. In the last few weeks, however, many new aspects of this question have become apparent. Some of our longest standing, most respected, and well-known users, such as Mari-Lou A have made important points and contributions. The wording of the question now gives more background regarding the change on the StackOverflow site, which is where the question originates from.

As new advantages and disadvantages of keeping or losing the accepted answer feature have emerged, the trend in voting has shifted considerably—as happened on [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/should-accepted-answers-appear-first-just-above-the-highest-scored-answer-or-s). Several users here have changed their votes, including esteemed ELL Moderators.

At the time of writing, the vote is tied 15/15. It would be great of we could come out with a clear and decisive majority, whichever way that is. If there isn't a very clear and decisive majority, the Powers That Be at SE will make the decision for us.

In light of the new points that have emerged on both sides, I invite readers to revisit the question [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/should-accepted-answers-appear-first-just-above-the-highest-scored-answer-or-s). If you haven't voted, I urge you to do so. We need your valued opinion! Just as importantly, if not more so, if you already voted, please revisit the page, see what's happened, and see if you'd [like to change your vote, or keep it the same](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/should-accepted-answers-appear-first-just-above-the-highest-scored-answer-or-s).

Keep rocking in the free world!

---

<sup>If you care a lot about this kind of stuff, perhaps you might consider being a mod! Nominations are open [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1). Do it!</sup>